# Duplicates because Oracle is too fast or multithread?

Tags: java, performance, web-services, oracle11g, duplicates

I have a problem with duplicate records arriving in our database via a Java web service, and I think it's to do with Oracle processing threads.

Using an iPhone app we built, users add bird observations to a new site they visit on holiday. They create three records at "New Site A" (for example). The iPhone packages each of these three records into separate JSON strings containing the same date and location details.

On Upload, the web service iterates through each JSON string.

Iteration/Observation 1. It checks the database to see if the site exists, and if not, creates a new site and adds the observation into a hanging table. 

Iteration/Obs 2. The site should now exists in the database, but it isn't found by the database site check in Iteration 1, and a second new site is created.

Iteration/Obs 3. The check for existing site NOW WORKS, and the third observation is attached to one of the existing sites. So the web service and database code does work.

The web service commits at the end of each iteration.

Is the reason for the second iteration not finding the new site in the database due to delays in Oracle commit after it's been called by the Java, so that it's already started processing iteration 2 by the time iteration 1 is truly complete, OR is it possible that Oracle is running each iteration on a separate thread?

One solution we thought about was to use Thread.sleep(1000) in the web service, but I'd rather not penalize the iPhone users.

Thanks for any help you can provide.
Iain

Comment: make sure your commit method returns only after the changes are actually made in the DB.

Comment: I doubt whether it's Oracle being too slow when committing. How are you checking whether a site exists? Is it based on a name, location? Are you sure the sites are completely equal based on those characteristics?

Comment: Thanks - it's based on a variety of check criteria. The code works because the third iteration picks up a match, it's just the second iteration that doesn't. I wonder if I should commit more often rather than just once at the end of the JSON processing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like a race condition to me. Probably your observation 1 and 2 are arriving very close to each other, so that 1 is still processing when 2 arrives.  Oracle is ACID-compliant, meaning your transaction for observation 2 cannot see the changes made in transaction one, unless this one was completed *before* transaction two started.

If you need a check-then-create functionality, you'd best synchronize this at a single point in your back end.

Also, add a constraint in your DB to avoid the duplication at all costs.

Comment: A constraint would be nice, but only if I can handle any errors right, which is complex given the phone/web server/database setup (complex for me at least). My check-then-create functionality should mean a constraint is not needed, but alas....

Comment: as a general rule, every constraint you can add on db, you should add on the db.  Your database should distrust your application.  On the app, run the check-then-create in its own transaction, and synchronize it so that only one thread uses it at a time.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an Oracle problem; Thread.sleep would be a poor solution, especially since you don't know root cause.

Your description is confusing.  Are the three JSON strings sent in one HTTP request?  Does the order matter, or does processing any of them first set up the new location for the ones that follow?

What's a "hanging table"?

Is this a parent-child relation between location and observation?  So the unit of work is to INSERT a new location into the parent table followed by three observations in the child table that refer back to the parent?

I think it's a problem with your queries and how they're written.  I can promise you that Oracle is fast enough for this trivial problem.  If it can handle NASDAQ transaction rates, it can handle your site.

I'd write your DAO for Observation this way:

```
public interface ObservationDao {
    void saveOrUpdate(Observation observation);
}
```

Keep all the logic inside the DAO.  Test it outside the servlet and put it aside.  Once you have it working you can concentrate on the web app.

Comment: Hi - by Hanging Table, I mean a different table with FK on site_id - sorry poor choice of words. Your parent-child description is spot on, observations are attached to locations. Each JSON is sent in separate HTTP requests. I also believe Oracle fast enough, just stumped.

Comment: How are you managing transactions?  Are they hand coded, or are you using Spring or JPA?

Comment: Good question. Hand coded I guess since we don't use Spring. These are RESTful web services.

Comment: So it's autoCommit(false) on the connection, followed by commit or rollback on error?  Do you do that in a filter?  What's the isolation?  SERIALIZED is the highest you can get.